# Sourcing a shell script containing "typeset -r VAR=value"

Tags: linux, ksh

What is a good way to modify a script A containing

`"typeset -r VAR=value"`

to make the script repeatable (while maintaining the statement)?

Currently, the script in question is being dotted in by the user's .profile at login time and then dotted in again by other scripts which the user runs from the command line.

As is, the script will error out on subsequent runs because VAR will already be read only.

`uname -a: Linux demon 2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 10 15:42:40 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Problem Update:

If you comment out the dotting in of Script A by the user's `.profile` script, then upon login Script B which dots in Script A can be run over and over with no problem. However, if you then run Script A from the command line, subsequent calls of Script B error out.

What explains this behavior?

- Appears to be because the `.profile` runs in the biggest shell on the system while Script B runs in a temporary subshell.

How is it fixed?

- How can Script B be updated so that it checks for the readonlyness and value of VAR before trying to set VAR's value and making VAR read only?

Comment: Are you running the script or sourcing it?  I can only duplicate the problem by sourcing the script;  try running it instead.

Comment: The script is dotted in by the user's .profile script; it is subsequently dotted in by other scripts the user chooses to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
test -z "${VAR+set}" && typeset -r VAR=value
```

Comment: This will check if the length of ${VAR-x} is zero but what is ${VAR-x}?

Comment: If $VAR is unset, then ${VAR-x} is x, otherwise it is $VAR.  So ${VAR-x} is empty only if VAR is set to the empty string.  (As opposed to ${VAR:-x} which is x if VAR is unset or is empty.)

Comment: Cool, what is the - operator called?

Comment: So if $VAR is empty, we want to execute "typeset -r VAR=value".  Returning true on the left-hand side in this case would work.

Comment: Ah okay, it seems to make sense now. The second one ${VAR:-x} is even better and we need x to have zero length.

Comment: How can we make x the empty string?

Comment: So just "test -z ${VAR:-} && typeset -r VAR=value" should work.. testing it.

Comment: Ok this will check if the variable is set, but we should also check if VAR is set to value.

Comment: Thanks William! Your answer is an improvement over the current script. We will likely check to see if VAR!=value on the left hand side. Then, if VAR and value are not equal, we will try to set VAR to value and make VAR readonly. It's not perfect, but it is better. Another idea is for us to keep track of if the script has already been run. Then if it has been run, we can skip the statement.

Comment: @MDC  My apologies.  My original solution is incorrect, and may have caused you some confusion.  I will now update it to the more idiomatic method of checking that a variable is set.

Comment: Problem solved.. /etc/profile was exporting $USER and our user .profile was then calling script A which set $USER and made it read only.. we added a check to see if $USER's val is not correct.. if it is not correct, we try to set it and then make it read only.. and if it is correct then we just make it read only. With this change, Script A can be dotted by our user's profile.  Thanks again guys! Cheers, MDC